# How to configure Angular Provider in unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-ngmock

I'm trying to create tests for a provider, but I can't seem to configure it in the test. Here's my provider with which I'm configuring a service with a url when it gets instantiated:

```
angular.module('PRXHttpData', [])
.provider('HttpData', function(){

    var url;

    this.setUrl = function(_url_){
        url = _url_;
    };

    this.$get = function(){
        return new HttpDataService(url);
    }

});

function HttpDataService(url){
    this.url = url;
}
```

Here's my test setup:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('PRXHttpData');
});

var HttpDataProvider;

beforeEach(inject(function (_HttpData_) {

    HttpDataProvider = _HttpData_;

}));
```

I tried doing:

```
 beforeEach(function () {
     angular.mock.module('PRXHttpData').config(function(HttpData){
         HttpData.setUrl('test/url');
     });
 });
```

But it gives me the error "Cannot read property 'config' of undefined"

**How can I configure my provider in my test?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.mock.module()` doesn't return an Angular module and can't be chained.

As said in [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module#usage), it accepts functions as arguments:

> any number of modules which are represented as string aliases or as anonymous module initialization functions.

These functions are invoked during `config` phase. It should be

```
angular.mock.module('PRXHttpData', function(HttpDataProvider){ ... });
```

Comment: I've corrected the mistake that was pasted from original code. It should be `HttpDataProvider`.